# Decrypt Function Equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, encryption

I have this function to decrypt connection strings in VB .NET, and I try to bring it to C#:

```
Function DecryptText(strText As String, ByVal strPwd As String)
    Dim i As Integer, c As Integer
    Dim strBuff As String

#If Not CASE_SENSITIVE_PASSWORD Then

    'Convert password to upper case
    'if not case-sensitive
    strPwd = UCase$(strPwd)

#End If

    'Decrypt string
    If Len(strPwd) Then
        For i = 1 To Len(strText)
            c = Asc(Mid$(strText, i, 1))
            c = c - Asc(Mid$(strPwd, (i Mod Len(strPwd)) + 1, 1))
            strBuff = strBuff & Chr$(c & &HFF)
        Next i
    Else
        strBuff = strText
    End If
    DecryptText = strBuff
End Function
```

I tried with these two ways:

```
public static string DesencriptarCadena(this string cadena, string llave = "asdf")
{
    try
    {
        cadena = cadena.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "");
        byte b = 0;
        string strBuff = "";
        System.Text.Encoding encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;

        for (int i = 0; i < cadena.Length; i++)
        {
            b = encoding.GetBytes(cadena.ToCharArray(), i, 1)[0];
            int ind = i % llave.Length;
            b -= encoding.GetBytes(llave.ToCharArray(), ind, 1)[0];
            strBuff += encoding.GetChars(new byte[] { Convert.ToByte((int)b & +0xff) })[0];
        }

        return strBuff;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return cadena;
    }

}
```

or this other way:

```
public static string DesencriptarCadena(this string cadena, string llave = "asdf")
{
    try
    {
        cadena = cadena.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "");
        int c;
        string strBuff = "";
        System.Text.Encoding encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;

        for (int i = 0; i < cadena.Length; i++)
        {
            int ind = i % llave.Length;
            c = cadena[i];
            c -= llave[ind];
            strBuff += Convert.ToChar(c & +0xff);
        }

        return strBuff;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return cadena;
    }

}
```

But, it doesn't work. Can someone explain to me what I should  do?

In the first way return:

```
ÞÓÚÏË×ÞÓÚÏË×ÞÓÚÏ    ÞÓÚÏË×ÞÓÚÏú×ÞÓÚÏË×ÞÓÚÏË×ÞÓÚÏË×ÞÚÏË×ÞÓÚÏË×Þ
```

In the second: `NúÎCÄÁÎî`

It is not returning the decrypted connection string.

Comment: "but, doesn't work." why?  Add details in an [edit].

Comment: Please tell me you aren't encrypting passwords for reasons of authentication.  That's what hashing is for.

Comment: Also, XOR is trivially easy to crack.

Comment: in the first way return:
ÞÓÚÏË×ÞÓÚÏË×ÞÓÚÏ ÞÓÚÏË×ÞÓÚÏú×ÞÓÚÏË×ÞÓÚÏË×ÞÓÚÏË×ÞÚÏË×ÞÓÚÏË×Þ

in the second:
 NúÎCÄÁÎî

not return the connection string decrypted

Comment: I'll never get why VB programmers do things like "Chr$(c & &HFF)". Here you have a function 'Chr' that takes an integer argument and you decide to concatenate two perfectly fine integers to produce a string and pass that instead of adding the two integers.

Comment: i program in C# but here they explain it well. http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?331588-wat-does-amp-HFF-do#post_1965098

Answer (score 0):

http://converter.telerik.com has always done great by me for these types of conversions. Let me know how this works.

```
public object DecryptText(string strText, string strPwd)
{
int i = 0;
int c = 0;
string strBuff = null;

#if Not CASE_SENSITIVE_PASSWORD

//Convert password to upper case
//if not case-sensitive
strPwd = Strings.UCase(strPwd);

#endif

//Decrypt string
if (Strings.Len(strPwd)) {
    for (i = 1; i <= Strings.Len(strText); i++) {
        c = Strings.Asc(Strings.Mid(strText, i, 1));
        c = c - Strings.Asc(Strings.Mid(strPwd, (i % Strings.Len(strPwd)) + 1, 1));
        strBuff = strBuff + Strings.Chr(c + 0xff);
    }
} else {
    strBuff = strText;
}
return strBuff;
}
```

Comment: yes i try with this way, but Strings.Len() not is an method, and Strings.Asc and Strings.Chr and Strings.Mid.

Comment: You need to reference Microsoft.VisualBasic. Strings is inside of that assembly.

Comment: in theory Asc() should work (int)char or getting the byte from the char, true?

Comment: `Strings.Len` returns an `int` so it's not going to work in an `if` statement in `C#`.

Comment: This is a flaw in the original code then. In VB Len(string) also returns an int. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxsw58z6(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @Christopher I'm not 100% sure, but I'm guessing VB.Net implicitly converts integers to booleans.  Possibly for backwards compatibility to older version of VB?

Comment: @Juharr Yes, I just looked into it and you are correct about that. My mistake. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

After including the Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly, I added two using statements:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices;
```

I compiled it and decompiled it with dotPeek. It resulted in this:

```
    public static object DecryptText(string strText, string strPwd)
    {
        string str = string.Empty;
        strPwd = Strings.UCase(strPwd);
        if ((uint)Strings.Len(strPwd) > 0U)
        {
            int num1 = 1;
            int num2 = Strings.Len(strText);
            int Start = num1;
            while (Start <= num2)
            {
                int num3 = checked(Strings.Asc(Strings.Mid(strText, Start, 1)) - Strings.Asc(Strings.Mid(strPwd, unchecked(Start % Strings.Len(strPwd)) + 1, 1)));
                str = str + Conversions.ToString(Convert.ToChar(Conversions.ToString(num3) + Conversions.ToString((int)byte.MaxValue)));
                checked { ++Start; }
            }
        }
        else
            str = strText;
        return (object)str;
    }
```

Comment: The original VB code didn't specify a return type. So it defaults to object. Decompiling it to c# results in it explicitly being an object.